# Обработка callback_query от телеграма в php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, архитектура

Есть вполне себе рабочий бот, который корректно работает и обрабатывает все коллбеки от inline-кнопок. Проблема в том, что сейчас обработка осуществлена следующим образом (просто пример, не фрагмент кода):

```
if ($callback_data == 'save'){
    //some code
}
else if ($callback_data == 'connect'){
    //some code
}
```

И так далее. Каждый блок if обрабатывает инлайн-клавиатуру, и проблема в том, что их количество медленно, но верно увеличивается. Хотел попросить совета, как можно реорганизовать код, чтобы избежать портянки ифов в обозримом будущем?

Answer (score 1):

Тут два варианта, первый это использовать конструкцию switch ... case, к примеру:

```
switch ($var) {
      case 'save':
         echo 'save';
         break;
      case 'connect':
         echo 'connect';
         break;
      case 'exit' //добавление нового условия
         echo 'exit';
         break;
}
```

Это просто вариант, но я вам рекомендую прочитать про полиморфизм, ибо второй вариант, более элегантный связан именно с ним. К примеру:

```
class A
{
      function getMethods($function, $attribute)
      {
           if(function_exists($function)) // Поиск метода в нашем классе
           {
              call_user_func($function, $attribute); // Если метод найден - вызываем его
           }
           else
           {
               throw new \Exception('Метод не найден');
           {
     }

     function save($data)
     {
        // отрабатываем метод 
     }

     function connect($data)
     {
        // отрабатываем метод 
     }
}
```

Заметьте, этот вариант лучше, так как он легко масштабируется не модифицируя ваш основной код.

Comment: Спасибо! Второй способ - это то, что я искал)